# Scala iteration over lines in two files

Tags: scala, iteration

I have got two datasets Orig/Match and I wanna different matching on name columns. Iteration is working only for the first row, than it print name column from row number 2, but the iteration over Orig dataset not continue. It seems that two For cycles is not the right approach. :(

Thanks of help.

```
object poc {

  // similarity methods
  def lv_distance(s1: String, s2: String) = {
    LevenshteinMetric.compare(s1, s2)
  }

  def jv_distance(s1: String, s2: String) = {
    JaroWinklerMetric.compare(s1, s2)
  }

  // phonetic methods
  def mp_distance(s1: String, s2: String) = {
    MetaphoneMetric.compare(s1, s2)
  }

  def sx_distance(s1: String, s2: String) = {
    SoundexMetric.compare(s1, s2)
  }

  // output definition
  def printDistance(s1: String, s2: String) = println("%s -> %s, Levenshtein: %s, JaroWinkler: %s, Soundex: %s, Metaphone: %s"
    .format(s1, s2, lv_distance(s1, s2).get, jv_distance(s1, s2).get, sx_distance(s1, s2).get, mp_distance(s1, s2).get))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fileNameOrig = io.Source.fromFile(args(0), "iso-8859-1")
    val fileNameMatch = io.Source.fromFile(args(1), "iso-8859-1")

    for (lineMatch <- fileNameMatch.getLines()) {
      val colsMatch = lineMatch.split(",").map(_.trim)
      println(1, s"${colsMatch(0)}")
      for (lineOrig <- fileNameOrig.getLines()) {
        val colsOrig = lineOrig.split(",").map(_.trim)
        println(2, s"${colsOrig(6)}")
        printDistance(s"${colsOrig(6)}", s"${colsMatch(0)}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output example: with help print

```
(1,Jan Rock)
(2,Jem Rog)
Jem Rog -> Jan Rock, Levenshtein: 4, JaroWinkler: 0.7214285714285713, Soundex: true, Metaphone: false
(2,Jan Rock)
Jan Rock -> Jan Rock, Levenshtein: 0, JaroWinkler: 1.0, Soundex: true, Metaphone: true
(2,Jen Rack)
Jen Rack -> Jan Rock, Levenshtein: 2, JaroWinkler: 0.8500000000000001, Soundex: true, Metaphone: true
(2,Susan Rock)
Susan Rock -> Jan Rock, Levenshtein: 3, JaroWinkler: 0.8583333333333334, Soundex: false, Metaphone: false
(1,Susan Rock)
```

Comment: I suppose you need to do something like `(fileNameMatch.getLines() zip fileNameOrig.getLines())` and iterate over resulting pairs. I don't have scala compiler at hand, so cannot give you exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop consumes the entire file on the first outer iteration, so when you read the next line from the outer file, the inner iterator is already empty.

Try reading the whole file ahead of the loop:

```
  val outer = fileNameMatch.getLines()
  val inner =  fileNameOrig.getLines().toList
  for { 
    lineMatch <- outer
    lineOrig <- inner
    //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) extract column with name to list (getlines, split, map, s"${colsMatch(0)}" etc. append to list)

```
var match = List[String]();
match ::= s"${colsMarch(0)}";
println(match.reverse)
```

2) list cross(product) join

```
val f1 = fileNameOrig.getLines().toList
val f2 = fileNameMatch.getLines().toList

implicit class Crossable[X](xs: Traversable[X]) {
  def cross[Y](ys: Traversable[Y]) = for { x <- xs; y <- ys } yield (x, y)
}

println(f1 cross f2)
```

3) iterate over rows in list